# Django: Create profile page creates everything except Multiple Choice Field in the database

Tags: django

I am using the same form for `profile_edit` and `create_profile` functionality. It is updating the multi-choice values in the `profile_edit` page but does not create in `create_profile`.

Below is the form code in `forms.py`

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    full_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    current_position = forms.CharField(required=True)
    about_me = forms.Textarea(attrs={'required':True})
    topic_name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Topic.objects.all())


    class Meta:
        model = Profile 
        fields =(
            "full_name",
            "current_position",
            "about_me",
            "topic_name",
            )
```

Below is the `views.py` for profile creation

```
def create_profile(request, user_id):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
            form.user = user
            print(form.topic_name.all()) # Prints empty queryset
            form.save()
            return redirect("profile_view", user_id=user_id)
        else:
            context = {"form": form}
            return render(request, "profile/create_profile.html", context)
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
        context = {
            "form": form
        }
        return render(request, "profile/create_profile.html", context)
```

Below is `Model.py`

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.topic

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True)
    current_position = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    about_me = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True)
    topic_name = models.ManyToManyField(Topic)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Both `create_profile` and `edit_profile` templates are exactly the same.

It saves everything except Multichoice field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `save(commit=False)`,
you need to use `mymodelform.save_m2m()` below `save(commit=True)` on your ModelForm,
because many to many relationships cannot be saved without an ID.
see this [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

so in your **views.py**

```
if form.is_valid():
   profile = form.save(commit=False)
   user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
   profile.user = user
   profile.save()
   form.save_m2m()
   return redirect("profile_view", user_id=user_id)
```